# Algebra-only vector product question

Tags: vector-analysis

In the case when a=ai, b=bj and c=ck, where a, b, and c are positive scalar constants, determine the equation of the plane (which contains a, b, and c) in the form r.n=d, where the components of n and the value of the scalar constant d are to be given in terms of a, b, and c.

I'm having trouble with this question because I don't know what to cross to find n. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: if $i,j,k$ are the basis vector in ${\Bbb{R}}^3$ then $ai,bj,ck$ can't be in a plane

Comment: @janmarqz:  The three vectors are not, but the three points at the ends are in a plane.  I believe that is the plane desired.

Comment: Am I correct that b-a would be bx-ax, by-ay, bz-az?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interpretation of your question is the way that Ross Millikan suggested, then you have to solve the problem as though there are three points in the plane $A(a,0,0)$, $B(0,b,0)$, and $C(0,0,c)$. The hint that Ross Millikan gave you was to find the two vectors in the plane. And its clear, from your comments, that you found the normal vector which if I am not mistaken is $$n=\begin{pmatrix} -a \\[0.3em] b \\[0.3em] 0 \\[0.3em] \end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix} -a \\[0.3em] 0 \\[0.3em] c \\[0.3em] \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} bc \\[0.3em] ac \\[0.3em] ab \\[0.3em] \end{pmatrix}$$ You can find $d$ if you first find the Cartesian equation which is by expanding $n\cdot r=(bc )x+(ac)y+ab(z)$. You then replace a point, say $A$, and find that $d=abc$.

Therefore the normal vector equation of the plane is,

$$\begin{pmatrix} bc \\[0.3em] ac \\[0.3em] ab \\[0.3em] \end{pmatrix} \bullet \ r=abc$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Two vectors in the plane are $\vec b - \vec a$ and $\vec c - \vec a$

Comment: So b-a would be bx-ax, by-ay, bz-az, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: And where do I go from here? I've crossed them but just get a long string of algebra.